# Converting httppost to httpget

Tags: c#

I found this code which works great for me, which is easy to use but I'm kinda stuck with a simple problem

```
private static string DoGET(string URL, NameValueCollection QueryStringParameters = null, NameValueCollection RequestHeaders = null)
        {
            string ResponseText = null;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (RequestHeaders != null)
                    {
                        if (RequestHeaders.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (string header in RequestHeaders.AllKeys)
                                client.Headers.Add(header, RequestHeaders[header]);
                        }
                    }
                    if (QueryStringParameters != null)
                    {
                        if (QueryStringParameters.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (string parm in QueryStringParameters.AllKeys)
                                client.QueryString.Add(parm, QueryStringParameters[parm]);
                        }
                    }
                    byte[] ResponseBytes = client.DownloadData(URL);
                    ResponseText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ResponseBytes);
                }
                catch (WebException exception)
                {
                    if (exception.Response != null)
                    {
                        var responseStream = exception.Response.GetResponseStream();

                        if (responseStream != null)
                        {
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                            {
                                //Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return ResponseText;
        }
```

I want to convert this code into a HTTP Post method and when I changed client.DownloadData(URL) to client.UploadValues(URL), it requires the NameValueCollection as the second parameter but the top portion of the code have added them into the client,

Do I not add "QueryStringParameters" into the client and use it as the 2nd parameter instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked: Do I not add "QueryStringParameters" into the client and use it as the 2nd parameter instead?

The answer is: Yes

### Explanation

The `QueryString` property of the WebClient class is used to build name/value pairs that are appended to the WebClient URI as a query string, and therefore used mostly in Get requests.

Assuming you wanted, you could still do:

```
byte[] ResponseBytes = client.UploadValues(URL, client.QueryString);
```

But this will obviously be wasteful since you could have passed it directly as well.